# trough detection algorithm returns peak data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-science

hi i have made an algorithm to detect the time taken for a wave from beginning of a trough  to next through to calculate duration all separate waves but the through function keeps returning some peaks

**the algorithm**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import peakutils

# Read the data from the CSV file
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')

# Convert the first column to datetime format
df['Column1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Column1'])

# Convert the second column to numeric type
df['Column2'] = df['Column2'].astype(int)


def through(arr, n, num, i, j):

    # If num is smaller than the element
    # on the left (if exists)
    if (i >= 0 and arr[i] < num):
        return False

    # If num is smaller than the element
    # on the right (if exists)
    if (j < n and arr[j] < num):
        return False
    return True

# Function that returns true if num is
# smaller than both arr[i] and arr[j]
def isTrough(arr, n, num, i, j):

    # If num is greater than the element
    # on the left (if exists)
    if (i >= 0 and arr[i] < num):
        return False

    # If num is greater than the element
    # on the right (if exists)
    if (j < n and arr[j] < num):
        return False
    return True

def printPeaksTroughs(arr, n):

    print("Peaks : ", end = "")

    # For every element
    for i in range(n):

        # If the current element is a peak
        if (through(arr, n, arr[i], i - 1, i + 1)):
            # print(arr[i], end = " ")
            peaks_info = np.vstack((arr[i],arr2[i])).T
            print(peaks_info)
    print()

    print("Troughs : ", end = "")

    # For every element
    for i in range(n):

        # If the current element is a trough
        if (isTrough(arr, n, arr[i], i - 1, i + 1)):
            print(arr[i], end = " ")

# Driver code
arr = df['Column2']
arr2=df['Column1']

# arr = [5, 10, 5, 7, 4, 3, 5]
# arr2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
n = len(arr)

printPeaksTroughs(arr, n)
```

**this is the result i am getting**

```
[[87 Timestamp('2023-03-14 14:20:08')]]
[[86 Timestamp('2023-03-14 14:22:23')]]        
[[86 Timestamp('2023-03-14 14:23:30')]]        
[[86 Timestamp('2023-03-14 14:24:38')]]        
[[262 Timestamp('2023-03-14 14:34:46')]]       
[[262 Timestamp('2023-03-14 14:35:54')]]       
[[91 Timestamp('2023-03-14 14:56:09')]]        
[[262 Timestamp('2023-03-14 15:07:25')]]       
[[262 Timestamp('2023-03-14 15:08:32')]]       
[[262 Timestamp('2023-03-14 15:09:40')]]       
[[89 Timestamp('2023-03-14 15:31:03')]]        
[[86 Timestamp('2023-03-14 15:35:33')]]
[[86 Timestamp('2023-03-14 15:36:41')]]
[[86 Timestamp('2023-03-14 15:37:49')]]
[[262 Timestamp('2023-03-14 15:49:04')]]
[[95 Timestamp('2023-03-14 16:07:05')]]
[[262 Timestamp('2023-03-14 16:17:13')]]
```

as you can see it some times picks up the value 262 which is the highest value in the data set
the graph of the data on same algorithm also detects these peaks as throughs

[image: data graph]

here the green arrows show the through and red ones are for peaks

i want the data from 1st through to 2nd through to be set as 1st wave then the through at the end of 1st wave is regarded as start of 2nd wave for example

[image]

this is the data in written form since i cant upload the csv file. these are only 1st few peaks

```
Column1,Column2
2023-03-14 14:00:59.0,195.80
2023-03-14 14:02:06.0,174.20
2023-03-14 14:03:14.0,156.76
2023-03-14 14:04:21.0,142.36
2023-03-14 14:05:29.0,131.00
2023-03-14 14:06:37.0,122.00
2023-03-14 14:07:44.0,114.91
2023-03-14 14:08:52.0,109.18
2023-03-14 14:10:00.0,104.56
2023-03-14 14:11:07.0,100.74
2023-03-14 14:12:15.0,97.93
2023-03-14 14:13:22.0,95.45
2023-03-14 14:14:30.0,93.43
2023-03-14 14:15:37.0,91.85
2023-03-14 14:16:45.0,90.73
2023-03-14 14:17:53.0,89.49
2023-03-14 14:19:00.0,88.59
2023-03-14 14:20:08.0,87.91
2023-03-14 14:21:15.0,87.13
2023-03-14 14:22:23.0,86.68
2023-03-14 14:23:30.0,86.23
2023-03-14 14:24:38.0,86.23
2023-03-14 14:25:45.0,108.61
2023-03-14 14:26:53.0,142.70
2023-03-14 14:28:01.0,175.89
2023-03-14 14:29:08.0,203.79
2023-03-14 14:30:16.0,225.84
2023-03-14 14:31:23.0,241.25
2023-03-14 14:32:31.0,253.29
2023-03-14 14:33:39.0,262.18
2023-03-14 14:34:46.0,262.29
2023-03-14 14:35:54.0,262.29
2023-03-14 14:37:01.0,262.29
2023-03-14 14:38:09.0,260.83
2023-03-14 14:39:16.0,235.51
2023-03-14 14:40:24.0,208.85
2023-03-14 14:41:31.0,185.45
2023-03-14 14:42:39.0,166.33
2023-03-14 14:43:46.0,150.35
2023-03-14 14:44:54.0,137.41
2023-03-14 14:46:01.0,127.06
2023-03-14 14:47:09.0,118.96
2023-03-14 14:48:17.0,112.55
2023-03-14 14:49:24.0,107.15
2023-03-14 14:50:32.0,103.10
2023-03-14 14:51:39.0,99.61
2023-03-14 14:52:47.0,96.80
2023-03-14 14:53:54.0,94.55
2023-03-14 14:55:02.0,92.75
2023-03-14 14:56:09.0,91.18
2023-03-14 14:57:17.0,97.70
2023-03-14 14:58:24.0,127.06
2023-03-14 14:59:32.0,161.04
2023-03-14 15:00:39.0,190.85
2023-03-14 15:01:47.0,214.81
2023-03-14 15:02:55.0,233.38
2023-03-14 15:04:02.0,247.21
2023-03-14 15:05:10.0,256.66
2023-03-14 15:06:17.0,262.29
2023-03-14 15:07:25.0,262.29
2023-03-14 15:08:32.0,262.29
2023-03-14 15:09:40.0,262.29
2023-03-14 15:10:47.0,262.29
2023-03-14 15:11:55.0,246.31
2023-03-14 15:13:02.0,219.65
2023-03-14 15:14:10.0,194.56
2023-03-14 15:15:17.0,173.53
2023-03-14 15:16:25.0,156.43
2023-03-14 15:17:33.0,142.03
2023-03-14 15:18:40.0,130.78
2023-03-14 15:19:48.0,121.89
2023-03-14 15:20:55.0,114.80
2023-03-14 15:22:03.0,109.18
2023-03-14 15:23:10.0,104.68
2023-03-14 15:24:18.0,101.19
2023-03-14 15:25:25.0,98.26
2023-03-14 15:26:33.0,95.90
2023-03-14 15:27:41.0,93.88
2023-03-14 15:28:48.0,92.41
2023-03-14 15:29:56.0,91.06
2023-03-14 15:31:03.0,89.94
2023-03-14 15:32:11.0,89.04
2023-03-14 15:33:18.0,88.03
2023-03-14 15:34:26.0,87.35
2023-03-14 15:35:33.0,86.79
2023-03-14 15:36:41.0,86.34
2023-03-14 15:37:49.0,86.34
2023-03-14 15:38:56.0,108.39
2023-03-14 15:40:04.0,142.59
2023-03-14 15:41:11.0,175.33
2023-03-14 15:42:19.0,203.00
2023-03-14 15:43:26.0,224.94
2023-03-14 15:44:34.0,240.91
2023-03-14 15:45:41.0,252.39
2023-03-14 15:46:49.0,260.71
2023-03-14 15:47:56.0,262.29
2023-03-14 15:49:04.0,262.29
2023-03-14 15:50:11.0,262.29
2023-03-14 15:51:19.0,259.14
2023-03-14 15:52:26.0,233.60
2023-03-14 15:53:34.0,207.39
2023-03-14 15:54:41.0,183.99
2023-03-14 15:55:49.0,164.98
2023-03-14 15:56:57.0,149.00
2023-03-14 15:58:04.0,136.06
2023-03-14 15:59:12.0,125.94
2023-03-14 16:00:19.0,117.84
2023-03-14 16:01:27.0,111.43
2023-03-14 16:02:35.0,106.25
2023-03-14 16:03:42.0,102.31
2023-03-14 16:04:50.0,98.94
2023-03-14 16:05:57.0,96.35
2023-03-14 16:07:05.0,95.34
```

Answer (score 1):

If the data is stationary (the magnitude of peaks and troughs does not differ much). For example, for `trough`, we check that the three values on the `left` are greater than the current value and on the `right`, the three values are greater than or equal. I used `List comprehension` instead of loops, as it is many times faster.
Write down the indices and substitute them in loc to fetch values.

This is taking into account if your indexes have an integer value (0, 1, 2 ....)

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df['Column1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Column1'])

period = 3

dn = [i for i in range(period, len(df) - period - 1) if
      (df.loc[i, 'Column2'] < df.loc[i - period:i - 1, 'Column2']).all() == True
      and (df.loc[i, 'Column2'] <= df.loc[i + 1:i + period, 'Column2']).all() == True]

up = [i for i in range(period, len(df) - period - 1) if
      (df.loc[i, 'Column2'] > df.loc[i - period:i - 1, 'Column2']).all() == True
      and (df.loc[i, 'Column2'] >= df.loc[i + 1:i + period, 'Column2']).all() == True]


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(df['Column1'], df['Column2'])
ax.plot(df.loc[dn, 'Column1'], df.loc[dn, 'Column2'], 'o', color='green', markersize=5)
ax.plot(df.loc[up, 'Column1'], df.loc[up, 'Column2'], 'o', color='red', markersize=5)
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

[image]
And to get the difference between the troughs:

```
df.loc[dn, 'Column1'].diff()
```

If you want to count the peaks from when the values start to drop. You need to take the condition greater than or equal to the left, and more to the right:

```
up = [i for i in range(period, len(df) - period - 1) if
      (df.loc[i, 'Column2'] >= df.loc[i - period:i - 1, 'Column2']).all() == True
      and (df.loc[i, 'Column2'] > df.loc[i + 1:i + period, 'Column2']).all() == True]
```

**Update 11.04.2023**

```
dn = [i for i in range(period, len(df) - period - 1) if
      (df.loc[i, 'Column2'] <= df.loc[i - period:i - 1, 'Column2']).all() == True
      and (df.loc[i, 'Column2'] < df.loc[i + 1:i + period, 'Column2']).all() == True]

arr = df.loc[dn, ['Column2', 'Column1']].values
print(arr)
```

Output

```
[[86.23 Timestamp('2023-03-14 14:24:38')]
 [91.18 Timestamp('2023-03-14 14:56:09')]
 [86.34 Timestamp('2023-03-14 15:37:49')]]
```

[image]

Comment: this is good but i need the through data with the time data in an array for example for 1st through[(86-91 28 mins),(91-87 20 mins)]
can u help me with that plz

Comment: explain step by step how to get them (where the calculation should start and end for each).

Comment: i want to return an array that gives me the start and end on the wave so from 1st through which in the given data  is 86.6 to next one which is 91 and for next wave it will be starting from 91 to next through which is 86.34 and the corresponding time value with it for the algorithm i wrote it return like this  ([[86 Timestamp('2023-03-14 14:24:38')]],[91 Timestamp('2023-03-14 14:56:09')]]) so i can calculate the duration of the wave that how many mins it lasted. and again i appreciate your help a lot

Comment: so the minimum is the last minimum (on the left there should be, as in the example, three values greater than or equal to it, and on the right three values greater). See update. Right?

Comment: i used the dn array from your code and was able to achive my desired result thanks

Comment: The one that was updated?

Comment: i did that before update i just saw the update thanks for that my friend

Comment: if the answer helped, you can check the box below the top and bottom triangles.

Comment: i am not clear what u said about the triangle do i mean the upvote i already did that